# What does "./" mean in Gulp.js?

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

I've been reading up on Gulp.  In the following code you'll notice that in the `gulp.src` and the `gulp.dest` that the path starts with `./`

```
gulp.src('./scss/*.scss')
  .pipe(sass({
    includePaths: ['bower_components/foundation/scss']
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
```

What is the purpose of the `./`? Would the code run any differently without the dot?

Comment: `./` means current directory. To be more specified, the folder where the working file is in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @niba said, this script prefix its paths with `./` only to precise the current working directory.

It's a little fancy since you're not supposed to launch a gulp task at another place than in the directory containing your gulpfile, and even if called in a child directory, it will change the path to the one of your gulpfile.

Note that it does not work the same way as when you're using it with `require`, since it's the path of the directory in which it was required that is used.